# Django-likes repeats the same post

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using the app [django-likes](https://github.com/praekelt/django-likes) and have managed to get it working. But I'm running into a very weird problem. The model "Story" is associated with the likes. Now the Story posts are repeated the number of votes they have -- for example, if they have 4 votes, they're actually repeated 4 times. Not sure what's going on. Any help much appreciated.

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    posts = Story.objects.all().order_by('votes')
    form = StoryForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Thanks for adding your mix!')

    return render_to_response('home.html',
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import secretballot, likes


class Story(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text

secretballot.enable_voting_on(Story)
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load likes_inclusion_tags %}



{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1 align=center>Add Your Mix!</h1>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
            <h1>{{ form_title }}</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="" >{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type='submit' class='btn' value='Add{{ button_submit }}' />
            </form>
        </div>

{% else %}

    <h1 align=center>Login and add a story!</h1>
    <p align=center><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/accounts/login/" role="button">Login!</a></p>
{% endif %}

{% for post in posts %}

<p>{{ post.text }} {% likes post %}</p>

{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `{% likes post %}`returns a number and Multiplies the string `{{ post.text }}` five times like python would. Try separating it or converting it to string.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. I tried this, but no. If I put just `{{ post.text }}` in the template, it gives me each text the number of times it's been liked, and if I separate it from `{% likes post %}`, the latter is also repeated the number of times it's liked. I think there may be something missing or wrong with [django-likes](https://github.com/praekelt/django-likes/tree/develop/likes).